# How to view tables created in a database

Tags: android

I am new to android. I created a data base named as example.db with some tables in SqlLite. It worked fine. It was also created in `data/data/com.mypackage.myapp/databases/example.db.`

Now, I need to open that database and see the content in the database. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Following only works on the Emulator or on a rooted phone.

Open your Command prompt (or Terminal)

```
1) Traverse to `\android-sdk-XXX\tools`
2) Type in `adb shell`
3) cd /data/data/com.mypackage.myapp/databases/
4) sqlite3 example.db
```

Now you have an SQL Interface for your  Database.

```
Select * from TableName;
```

Comment: Are you using a Phone? I was under the impression you were talking about the emulator. You can't access the DB of a phone, unless you have a `rooted` phone.

Answer (score 0):

you can see the contents of database by pull the database to desktop with extension .sqlite
for example abc.sqlite then install the sqlite manager for the firefox and then open that mangaer and select the connnect to open your database which will definately allow you to see the contents of your database as well as tables.